# How to initiate a Full Reboot/Shutdown on Windows 10 Fall Creators Update

Tags: windows-10, shutdown, reboot, windows-10-v1709

**Environment**: Windows 10 Fall Creators Update / 1709

**Background**: There is a new feature in the Fall Creators update where post reboot applications and browser windows are reopened to the state they were in before the reboot.

**Issue**: The only time I really reboot is when I no longer want the applications to be open. It's driving me crazy that I can't fully shutdown/reboot the machine.

**Solutions attempted** I always reboot by using Win+R and running `Shutdown -r -t 0`. The `-r` option should do a full reboot but that isn't working for me.

Any other suggestions or hacks to control via command-line on how to do a full reboot vs. this Zombie reboot (Which is a feature I like when I did not want to reboot and had to).

Comment: Don't go fooling around with alternative shutdown methods.  Instead, turn off the feature which is giving you problems.  Disable Windows 10 Cortana "Pick up where I left off".

Comment: Makes sense. I would like to be able to control it ideally such that by default it picks up where I left off but when I explicitly run the command with the right options it doesn't pick up

Comment: if you don't like my solution with turning it off run this command to fully shutdown: **shutdown /r /f /t 0**

Answer (score 3):

Open Cortana settings and [disable the option `Pick up where I left off`](https://www.ghacks.net/2017/10/25/block-reopening-of-programs-on-windows-10-start/)

[image]

Now the programs should no longer open again.

If this doesn't help, open **Group Policy Editor** (`gpedit.msc`) go to 
Computer Configuration -> Policies -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Windows Logon Option

Set the Policy Name: `Sign-in last interactive user automatically after a system-initiated restart` to **Disabled**.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunfately doesn't work on most recent version.

Comment: @AlexZhukovskiy which version? 1809?

Comment: I do have 1803.

Comment: @AlexZhukovskiy turn off the option "Use my sign-in info to automatically finish setting up my device and reopen my apps after an update or restart. " in settings app under "Settings > Accounts > Sign-In Options"

Comment: I don't have this option: https://i.imgur.com/XAxyAZp.png so I disabled it via gpedit (as you suggested), but it didn't work.

Comment: @AlexZhukovskiy I see the option in 1809. I no longer run 1803

Answer (score 0):

If you can use pskill, then use it to kill the winlogon process. This is a forced reboot and isn't recommended other than an emergency. If you have access to a command prompt then TASKKILL /F /IM winlogon.* will do the same.

Answer (score 0):

While the setting at Accounts > Sign-in options > "Use my sign-in info to automatically finish setting up my device and reopen my apps after an update or restart" works on some of my devices (1803 and 1809), it was hit and miss. This registry change, however, has been 100% effective at disabling this unwanted feature.

```
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System" /v DisableAutomaticRestartSignOn /t reg_dword /d 1 /f
```