# Windows 10 hibernates instead of shutting down, even though fast startup is disabled

Tags: windows, shutdown, hibernate, windows-10-v1709

I had recently installed a major windows update (Version 1709, build 16299.125), and since then I have noticed a strange problem: whenever I shutdown the computer having open programs, I still see them at the same state when I power it back on. It seems like my computer actually hibernates instead of fully shutting down.

After searching and reading many articles, I realized there's a built-in function called "Fast Startup", which is supposed to exit all programs and hibernate instead of shutting the computer down.

Thinking the "Fast Startup" function might didn't work well (by skipping the stage of exiting all programs), I tried to totally disable the function using the following method:

```
 1. Right click the Windows start menu button and choose Power Options.
    Click on Choose What the Power Button Does.
 2. If there is a Windows
    UAC shield at the top with Change Settings That Are Currently
    Unavailable, click it and choose Yes or enter your password to
    reopen the dialog with administrative privileges.
 3. At the bottom
    below Shutdown Settings, it will say Turn on Fast Startup
    (recommended). Deselect the option and press Save Changes.
```

Yet, my computer still remembers its previous state after I power it on from a (so-called) complete shutdown. Has anyone encountered a similar bug? Do you know how can I fix it?

Comment: "I tried to totally disable the function" What exactly did you try? "I had recently installed a major windows update" Which update? Please [edit] your question and don't answer in a comment.

Comment: i've updated the topic with the relevant information

Comment: The system is not hibernating. Yours sounds like a different problem (in v1709) [Stop Auto Reopen of Programs after Restart in Windows 10 » Winhelponline](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/stop-auto-reopen-programs-restart-windows-10/)

Answer (score 1):

To turn off *Hibernate*, open a CMD prompt as Administrator and enter:

> powercfg -h off

Combining that line with the following:

> shutdown /s /t 0

and saving it as a batch script, executed as Administrator, allows you to shutdown completely, rather than using Windows Fast Startup.

If you want to enable *Hibernate* again, enter:

> powercfg -h on

Comment: I guess that could be a nice workaround, but I want to restore the original behavior of the shutdown button.

Comment: @IdoDoron Technically speaking Windows 10 has always done a hybrid shutdown.  You just notice it more know because Windows now restores any application that was running.  Since hybrid shutdown requires the ability to hibernate disabling it makes a hybrid shutdown not possible.  Of course you also lose out on the speed advantages of said hybrid shutdown

Comment: @Ramhound, yes, and to safely dual-boot, I regularly turn *Hibernate* off, and on again when working just in Windows to speed startup.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Which is the reason your answer is correct and helpful

Comment: I have nothing against hybrid shutdown. I just want to disable the feature which restores all apps from the previous session. 
I actually mentioned in original description of my question, that I had already disabled hibernation, and it still remembered my computer's state the next time I turned it on. So I don't see how disabling hibernation helps me...

Answer (score 1):

You could open the control panel -> power options, select on the left 'Choose what the power button does' and change the option 'When I press the power button' as shown in the picture below.

[image: Power options]

If you still have the same problem, try to edit the power settings and change 'Allow hybrid sleep' to Off

[image: Edit power options - Allow hybrid sleep]

Answer (score 0):

Actually,  Win32Guy's comment was very helpful. He referred me to this link: [Stop Auto Reopen of Programs after Restart in Windows 10](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/stop-auto-reopen-programs-restart-windows-10/)

Seems like Windows 10 Fall Creators Update brought in a new feature, designed to remember all active programs before shutdown, so the user would be able to continue from where he's stopped, the next time he turns on his PC.

Unfortunately, from reading the article I couldn't find any way to disable the annoying feature. However, it does offer all kinds of workarounds... I suggest you read the article and look for the workaround that fits to you.

Comment: [there is a way](https://superuser.com/a/1264531/174557) to disable it in settings app

Comment: That option is actually missing in my PC! Went to Settings > Accounts > Sign-in Options and could not find that option there.

Comment: open cortana and click here on settings

Comment: Again, I don't have that option, and Cortana isn't available in my country.