# How to prevent Windows 10 from starting previous programs after system failure

Tags: windows-10

How to prevent Windows 10 from starting previous programs after system failure?

*My problem:* In company, I have Visual studio project with TFS, but via VPN. With my job, I need to turn it on always to remote control when needed.

Sometimes when our building manager guys turn off the light (don't as me about our company policy), my computer lost power, agrr. The next day I come, turn on computer and it auto start Visual studio without connecting to VPN, so my TFS got offline.

After that I must do many steps to make TFS online again (connect TFS again, change value in regedit.... [as in this post](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/24498/tfs-go-offline-consistently.html) )

So, how to start windows 10 without auto run previous programs (visual studio) after system failure?

Comment: I'm not going to put this as a proper answer since I haven't tested it myself but I read where you can go to Windows Settings > Accounts > Sign-in Options > uncheck "Use my sign-in info to automatically finish setting up my device and reopen apps after an update or restart"  and it will prevent what you're describing from happening (despite the fact that the description of that setting doesn't necessarily sound like it applies to your situation). It's worth a try.

Comment: See this post：https://superuser.com/questions/1229963/windows-10-disable-reopening-programs-after-restart-startup

Comment: @ottowang - There it goes. That's where I read it. Thanks.

Comment: @n8te I just added a link, I hope you don't mind. Have a nice day!

Comment: @ n8te and @ottowang: Thank you, I will try that solution!