# Windows 10 keeps reopening programs on startup, even I closed them

Tags: windows, windows-10

As mentioned in the title, every time I turn my computer back on, 1 or 2 programs which I had CLOSED before shutting it down are just relaunched.

The solution posted [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1229963/windows-10-disable-reopening-programs-after-restart-startup) doesn't work, since the option is not showing in my PC.

The strangest part is that this is happening with apps that I fully closed. I never shut my PC off when anything is open, and the thing is still restarting everything open again.

Comment: We should check if those application were added to startup options through System configuration\Start up

Answer (score 1):

Try these :

**Group Policy Edit**

- Open the Group Policy Editor (`gpedit.msc`)
- Navigate to :
  *Computer Configuration > Policies > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Windows Logon Option*
- Double-click on *Sign-in last interactive user automatically after a system-initiated restart*
- Set it to *Disabled* and click OK.

**Manual shutdown**

If nothing else works for you, use the command `shutdown /s /t 0` in the Run box or CMD.
You may also create and use a desktop shortcut for this command.

For Windows to use fast-boot on next boot, use the command `shutdown /s /hybrid /t 0`.

There are also reports that shutdown using the classical method of pressing
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> also avoids this problem.