# How to Stop Windows 10 From Reopening Previous Applications After Restarting PC

Tags: windows-10

I have these settings already off:

[image]

However, this does not work in practice. For instance, when restarting from “update windows” screen the apps are still reopened. How can I disable the feature completely?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1229963/windows-10-disable-reopening-programs-after-restart-startup?rq=1) question

Answer (score 2):

Newer versions of Windows 10 will restart some but not all apps regardless of that flag.

I close most apps (Office, Adobe, and Zoom at least) before shutting down.

This is the path of least resistance.

Answer (score 1):

Turning off "Restart apps" was the right action.

However, Explorer has a separate setting:

- Launch File Explorer
- Click the “View” tab on the Ribbon
- Click the “Options” button
- Go to the View tab
- Scroll down and locate the “Restore previous folder windows at logon” option.
  Ensure it’s unchecked.
- Click OK.

Now Windows will no longer reopen folder windows.

Comment: I have that unchecked already, yet sometimes it still happens.

Comment: Does it happen with specific apps?

Comment: Not specific. Most of them reopen, including Windows task manager.

Comment: I think the answer might be in the [link](https://superuser.com/questions/1229963/windows-10-disable-reopening-programs-after-restart-startup) that @Ramhound found.

Comment: I’ve clicked the link, but there’s no good answers there. I don’t want to use special tricks/shortcuts/shell commands to reboot Windows, I just want the “feature” gone, reliably so.

Comment: The [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1296139/8672) of disabling "Use my sign-in info to automatically f‌inish setting up my device after an update or restart" seems to fit your problem.

Comment: Was already off, updated the question replacing the screenshot. Doesn’t work, at least not reliably so.