# How to create app shortcut in Windows 8 / Windows 10

Tags: windows, shortcuts

For some apps (for example, Outlook) I can easily create a shortcut by hitting the start menu, typing in "Outlook" and right-click, open file location, and then I can right-click to Create Shortcut, or right-click-and-drag to Create Shortcut.

For other apps (for example, Mail) this does not work. When I right-click Mail, there is no "Open File Location."

I think the problem affects all windows store apps (but I could be wrong about that).

How can I create a shortcut to those apps? For example, how can I create a shortcut to Mail?

Comment: It sounds like you are using Windows 10 which would mean that `Mail` isn't a desktop application which means to my knowledge it cannot have a desktop shortcut.  You can pin the application to the taskbar though.  Of course there is an executable for `Mail`it just isn't in Program Files which you could create a shortcut to, since you can create a shortcut, to any file you want.  Yes;  I realize I said slightly contradictory statements, but they are different, so they are not actually contradictory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have placed this in an answer format as apposed to a comment only because it is a new enhancement that many people would likely want to use it.
Click on the Start button -> All Apps -> left click on "Mail" (or the windows store app required to short cut) and drag the icon to the desktop. This creates the short cut.
This option was added in build 9860 Source:
[Windows 10: Store apps can now have shortcuts on the desktop.](http://www.neowin.net/news/windows-10-store-apps-can-now-have-shortcuts-on-the-desktop)

Comment: There is one caveat: It works if you click the Start Menu, go to All Apps, and then drag the Mail app into (for example) the startup folder (shell:startup). But it does *not* work if you click the Start Menu, then type in "Mail" and attempt to drag the Mail app from the search results.

Comment: does not work for Win10Pro V1809 (answer from jay works)

Answer (score 2):

Borrowing straight from [@Mcore8x's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1100234/22177) for a similar question, you can navigate to

```
shell:AppsFolder
```

using the Run dialog or entering it into Explorer's address bar.

You can use those items show to create shortcuts onto Desktop or other places.