# How do you launch a Windows 10 app at startup?

Tags: windows-10, boot, modern-ui

Some programs (for example, Outlook) you can launch at startup by creating a shortcut. You press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, type in "shell:startup" to open the Startup folder, then you right-click Outlook, Open File Location, and right-click-and-drag to create a shortcut in the startup folder.

But with other apps (for example, Mail), it seems like you can't do that. (See [another question](https://superuser.com/questions/1019268/how-to-create-app-shortcut-in-windows-8-windows-10)).

So for apps like Mail, how can you make them launch automatically at startup?

*Edit:* An answer was found in the above referenced question. To create a shortcut for a Metro app like Mail, People, or Calendar, just drag it (normal left-click and drag). It works if you drag from Start Menu/All Apps, but does not work if you typed a search into the start menu. This works in Windows 10. I don't know if it works in Windows 8 or earlier.

Comment: @Edward Ned Harvey, Your method of launching an app is now do able. How to create a short cut in windows 10, see other question at :https://superuser.com/questions/1019268/how-to-create-app-shortcut-in-windows-8-windows-10

Comment: The top two answers right now for that question linked above are pretty crappy, but [@Mcore8x's underrated answer](http://superuser.com/a/1100234/22177) using `shell:AppsFolder` and `shell:Startup` works brilliantly!

Comment: @EdwardNedHarvey You should put the answer in an actual answer, and accept it.