# How to create desktop shortcuts for Microsoft Office apps in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office

This seems like it should be super straightforward, but I can't for the life of me figure it out.  In case it's helpful and relevant, I'm using Office 365.

Answer (score 1):

Borrowing from [@Mcore8x's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1100234/22177) for a similar question, you can navigate to

```
shell:AppsFolder
```

using the Run dialog or entering it into Explorer's address bar.

You can use those items show to create shortcuts onto Desktop or other places.

Answer (score 0):

> This seems like it should be super straightforward, but I can't for the life of me figure it out.

All you have to do is copy and paste the shortcut that exists at `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs` onto your desktop

[image]

Comment: @Albin - It does not matter.  I have looked at multiple machines with various versions of Office installed.

Comment: not really sure what you mean, but the app and desktop versions of office do have significat difference. For example the app version does not leave a regular shortcut in the startmenue (the desktopversion eg. 2016 does). Which app version did you check?

Comment: “The app version” are you talking about the one on the Windows Store?  I only have access to the desktop versions of Office 2016, Office 2019, and office 365.

Comment: I think so, but I'll have to check. What exactly is the application path in your shortcut? Something like "C:\someting\excel.exe"?